When I make an api request in the Next.js server side area, I cannot get the cookie value
What I want to do: I send a request to the backend in api/auth/me/route.js. I send the token to the backend with "Authorization: Bearer ${token}". As a result, the user information is returned to me successfully.
api/auth/me/route.js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const { value: token } = cookieStore.get("token") ?? { value: null };
    const response = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + "/me", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });

    const result = await response.json();

    return NextResponse.json(result);
}


http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me
As you can see, I receive user information.

On my page, I send a request to the api where I get the user information. The response I get back is { message: 'Unauthenticated.' } like this.
{ message: 'Unauthenticated.' }, this is the response I get when the token does not go to the backend or goes wrong.
import React from "react";

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me");

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    return res.json();
}

export default async function Page() {
    const data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
    return <div>home</div>;
}

http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me, when I request this address on the client side, the data comes without any problems, but I cannot get the data on the server side.
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me, when I enter, I can see the user information coming, when I send a request on the server side, I cannot get the data.
{ message: 'Unauthenticated.' }, I get this response.
{ message: 'Unauthenticated.' }, this is the response I get when the token does not go to the backend or goes wrong.

Try using await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me", { method: "GET" }), if this doesn't work, the problem might be because of next.js caching behavior, if that's the case, use await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me", { method: "GET", next: { revalidate: 0 } }) or  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me", { method: "GET", cache: "no-store" }) and see the result.

unfortunately, it didn't work

How is the token value being set and are you sure it is set there? Are you printing it maybe and seeing whats happening?

I'm probably getting this error because I can't access the cookie on the server side.
